# Recent expensive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

while checking the activity monitor i found some expensive queries and the execution plan for that is attached here [execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akVy6.png)

while checking it shows index seek is 66% what does it means ? How it became expensive query?
somebody please help

Comment: how long did the query take to run?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL SERVER 2012....

Comment: get the actual execution plan not the estimated one. and its 66% of that query, it may not be an 'expensive' query just thats where all the work is. If you filtering on VehicleID then you would expect it

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: @juergend: Actually the plan shows only small part of my stored procedure,the whole procedure takes around 16 seconds to complete.

Comment: 66% means that index seek take 66% of cost of total query. It doesn't mean much. All operators in query always add up to 100% so something have to take the cost. It generally good to see high percentages on index seek.

Comment: @kannan kandasamy: select top 1 @v_CancelScheduleid= VehicleScheduleid from VehicleSchedules WITH (NOLOCK) where vehicleid=@v_VehicleId
    and vehicleScheduleid not in (select isnull(vehicleScheduleid,0) from trip WITH (NOLOCK)) 
    and SchedStartTime<(select SchedStartTime from VehicleSchedules WITH (NOLOCK) where vehicleScheduleid=@ScheduleId)
    order by SchedStartTime desc

Comment: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @ Nenad Zivkovic: i am aware about the nolock but in my database real time scenario around 4000 hit will come in each 6 seconds and also display that using sp ...both insert and select using sp that is you i opted NOLOCK

Comment: Estimated Operator Cost is 0.02. I would not consider this to be expensive. Your problem is probably elsewhere. Especially for stored procedures you should not use estimated execution plan, it does not include loops and triggers. Have a look at your actual execution plan and it may become clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 subquery for result which is more cosltier, you can replace your subquery with joins or temp table.

Also you can index SchedStartTime of VehicleSchedules table and vehicleScheduleid column of trip table.

Note: Indexing will effect your DML query.

```
select top 1 @v_CancelScheduleid= VehicleScheduleid 
from VehicleSchedules WITH (NOLOCK) 
where vehicleid=@v_VehicleId 
and vehicleScheduleid not in (select isnull(vehicleScheduleid,0) from trip WITH (NOLOCK)) and SchedStartTime<(select SchedStartTime from VehicleSchedules WITH (NOLOCK) where vehicleScheduleid=@ScheduleId) order by SchedStartTime desc
```